# Trying to parse static json with backbone

Tags: json, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to output a list of objects with backbone / underscore, but I am getting a strange output in backbone. I am expecting a parsed data structure but as you can see what I getting back does not seem to be parsed in the right way. Any ideas?

Here is my json feed:

```
{"1":{"title":"Test Video Collection - blah (placeholder)","image":"imagenotavailable"},"2":{"title":"Camur Exerci Gemino","image":"public:\/\/gallery\/large\/imagefield_ieMdB8.jpg"},"3":{"title":"Abdo Nutus Sed","image":"public:\/\/gallery\/large\/imagefield_LtRKG1.png"},"4":{"title":"Quidne Vereor","image":"public:\/\/images\/video\/[current-date:custom:Y\/m\/d]\/imagefield_j7lGlq.jpg"},"5":{"title":"Ludus Ratis","image":"public:\/\/video-collections\/imagefield_aB3dpQ.png"},"6":{"title":"Appellatio Dolore Huic Vulputate","image":"public:\/\/gallery\/large\/imagefield_LtRKG1.png"}}
```

Here is my code:

```
 var itemModel = Backbone.Model.extend();
            var ItemList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: itemModel,
                url: 'http://l.blahcouk.sandbox:8080/franchise/videocollection/date/'
            });

            var ItemsView = Backbone.View.extend({
                template: _.template($('#bandlist_template').html()),
                render: function (eventName) {
                    _.each(this.model.models, function (items) {
                        console.log(items);
                        var lTitle = items.attributes['title'];
                        var lTemplate = this.template(items.toJSON());
                        $(this.el).append(lTemplate);
                    }, this);
                    return this;
                }
            });
            var lItems = new ItemList;
            var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: "body",

                render: function () {
                    var lItemsView = new ItemsView({
                        model: lItems
                    });
                    var lHtml = lItemsView.render().el;
                    $('#bands').html(lHtml);
                },

                initialize: function () {
                    var lOptions = {};
                    lOptions.success = this.render;
                    lItems.fetch(lOptions);
                }
            });
            var App = new AppView;
```

This is the structure of the output:

```
 r {cid: "c2", attributes: Object, collection: r, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object…}
_changing: false
_events: Object
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
1: Object
2: Object
image: "public://gallery/large/imagefield_ieMdB8.jpg"
title: "Camur Exerci Gemino"
__proto__: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
__proto__: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c2"
collection: r
__proto__: s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's happening I think - your JSON is valid, but not what backbone is expecting. Backbone collections expect an **array** of objects, not an object with numeric keys. So, what you need to do is alter your json output to be more like...

```
[
{"title":"Test Video Collection - blah (placeholder)","image":"imagenotavailable"},{"title":"Camur Exerci Gemino","image":"public:\/\/gallery\/large\/imagefield_ieMdB8.jpg"},
....
]
```

Rather than

```
{
"1": {"title":"Test Video Collection - blah (placeholder)","image":"imagenotavailable"},
"2": {"title":"Camur Exerci Gemino","image":"public:\/\/gallery\/large\/imagefield_ieMdB8.jpg"},
....
}
```

If you cannot alter this output, there are ways around this problem.

Comment: or if you don't have access to change the JSON, override parse in order to populate the collections and models correctly.